# Error installing Android SDK on Windows7 64

Tags: android, windows, sdk, failed-installation

Does anyone know if is it possible to install the Android SDK on a Win 7 64 bit machine
I've tried to do it severall time but thesre is always an issue

The two main issue are

Issue 1 : Sometime after installation the SDK Manager is unable to start bu I can't figure out why.

Issue 2 : To fix issue 1 It is suggested to run the Android.bat but Anroid.bat wont run on a Win7 machine (reg command does not exists on a Win7 machine)

Issue 3 : If by chance issue 1 does not occurs, I get another error during package installation

Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.1
Installing Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.1
**Failed to rename directory C:\Android\SDK\tools to C:\Android\SDK\temp\ToolPackage.old01.**

It seems to be an incredible amateurism work

Does anyone knows how to go further ?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Issue**2** ?? Maybe you have some firewall preventing the execution of the batch itself or some exe launched by the batch. - Issue**3**: `Failed to rename directory C:\Android\SDK\tools to C:\Android\SDK\temp\ToolPackage.old01` It seems that your path is in use by some application.

Comment: You probably have a permissions issue.